# How to find the heat flux for an ideal gas?

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics

The conservation equations for the fluid mechanics of an ideal gas are \begin{align*}\dot{\rho}+\nabla \cdot (\rho u)=0 \;&\text{(mass conservation)} \\ \dot{(\rho u)}+\nabla \cdot (\rho u u) + \nabla p=0 \;&\text{(momentum conservation)} \\ \dot{(\rho e)} +\nabla \cdot (\rho ue+\rho p + \rho Q)=0 \;&\text{(energy conservation)} \\ e=\frac{1}{2}u^2+\frac{3}{2}p \;&\text{(equation of state)}\end{align*} where $\rho$ is the density, $u$ the velocity, $p$ the pressure, $e$ the total energy (including the internal energy), and $Q$ the heat flux.

To solve these equations we need to know $Q$, what is the usual scheme used to determine Q for an ideal gas?

Comment: It's. equal to the thermal conductivity times the temperature gradient.

Comment: P.S., with a minus sign, of course.

Comment: @ChetMiller Not sure, but for a fluid wouldn't we use the convective heat transfer coefficient $h$ of the fluid rather than thermal conductivity $k$?

Comment: @BobD No..  These equations are for the region inside the fluid flow (not across an interface).

Comment: What happened to the viscous terms in your momentum conservation equation?  Gases exhibit significant viscosity under conditions where they display virtually perfect ideal gas behavior.